# how to focus from a TextField to a DropdownButton

Tags: flutter

I have a textfield and a dropdownbutton. I want when I move from the textfield, the dropdownbutton open and show its items, but i didnt found how do it

> Here is some flutter code that displays a dropdown and a textField...

```
  TextField(
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    controller: placeNameController,   
     onEditingComplete: () =>
      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                                ),
    DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
       value: selectedCategorie,
       autofocus: true,
       onChanged: () {
            setState(() {});
               },
     items: items)
```

Comment: Try using a focusNode

Comment: There's a way to change the keyboard enter button to next button that'll bring your DropDown in focus. I've implemented in one of my projects, but I'm unable to find it. If i do get it though i'll post in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **FocusNode**;

```
 FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

Add _**dropdownChange** in to your dropdown **onChange** method.

```
void _dropdownChange(val) {
 setState(() {
   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());///It will clear all focus of the textfield
   selectedDropdown = val;
 });
}
```

Comment: i didnt get you ? you mean put _dropdownChange  inside of onchange ?

Comment: Call _dropdownChange inside of onChange @Merym

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's works for me.

```
TextField(
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    controller: placeNameController,   
     onEditingComplete: () {
         FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
    },
                                ),
    DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
       value: selectedCategorie,
       autofocus: true,
       onChanged: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
            setState(() {});
               },
     items: items)
```